# cannot select desktop environments at login session

Tags: 12.10, unity, gnome

i cliked the weel at right top it showed number of DE  when i cliked with mouse nothing is happining as a result i cannot use lxde pla.. help me

Comment: Please be more specific. State exactly what you did to login, including trying to select lxde, and then giving up and logging into something else (presumably Unity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue i've run into before as well.

You have too many DE's installed. Ubuntu needs to add a scroll feature to LightDM ,but till then, try using the tab key to select down to the DE you want. I've heard that this works, but haven't tried it myself. I only use Unity, so my solution to problem was to remove some of the DE's I had.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. If the number or DE you have extends to the bottom of the screen you can't see the OK button. Use tab a few times and enter. The number of times varies by the location of the selected DE.  For some reason Selecting DE in 12.10 was a 2 step process. 13.04 is back to the original just click to select.